# InnoDB Cluster Mysql

Tags: mysql, cluster, innodb

tengo un cluster como puedo realizar una bajada limpia para poder reiniciar los nodos y luego subirlos en un Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7
version del mysql
| @@version |
+-----------+
| 8.0.25

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.